# Coldfusion Orm insert datetime: truncate error

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to insert a datetime into a mysql database using ORM.

I get this error:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '{ts '2013-11-21 06:33:45'}' 
    for column 'date' at row 1
```

I'm using this syntax to insert in database:

```
MyEntity.setCreationDate(Now())
```

I have set this in my object:

```
property name="creationDate" sqltype="datetime";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your property from this:

```
property name="creationDate" sqltype="datetime";
```

to this

```
property name="creationDate" ormtype="timestamp";
```